# Website hosted on Wordpress sending request to other servers remotely

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website hosted on Amazon Ubuntu.

Amazon reported that my server is sending a WordPress login attempt requests to other servers on Amazon.

My website is just a landing page with a contact form. How do I prevent such incidents?

Comment: Why negative vote? Suggest something. is it irrelevant?

Comment: Your site has basically been hacked, so either you install a fresh wordpress or sort out where it got hacked. And as a SO question this becomes very vague as there is no specific question now

Comment: Can you get info on what website url is being called?

Comment: there was a curl request in the source which I have removed. 

http://$xxx.31.253.227/cakes/?useragent=$botbotbot&domain=$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]

$xxx is the random number generated by a RANDOM function. 
I have removed this still Amazon is reporting that website is abusing other Ec2 instances

Comment: It seems malware issue on the site kindly check functions.php of your active theme. This will be the reason of the redirection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can block external http requests check adding

```
define( 'WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', true );
```

in wp-config.php

Answer (score 3):

Since you have already found a bad curl call in your source, I strongly suggest you check the integrity of your Wordpress installation.

If you have WP CLI available you can do this with the command `wp core verify-checksums`.

If you don't have WP CLI available you can use [this excellent solution by Jan Reilink](https://www.saotn.org/check-wordpress-core-files-integrity/) (either directly or as a starting point for your own code).

Either way you'll get output that tells you whether or not additional files have been modified (you could then restore them from the same WP version source). This will not be a catch-all-method in regards to malware, but I think it can be helpful in your specific situation.

Given that the code that's causing these requests is *not* part of the Wordpress core the answer to your question is some of the general best security practices for Wordpress:

- Keep Wordpress and plugins updated
- Use strong passwords for users
- Add a captcha and brute force protection to your login page if possible